# Vimeo player - listen for action events such as share

Tags: javascript, vimeo

I'm using the vimeo javascript SDK to make an overlay disappear on play and reappear on pause. This works great unless a user clicks one of the actions in the video such as share, as this pauses the video and puts the overlay back over the video.

How can I detect when an action button is clicked in the vimeo player?

```
vimeoPlayer.on('pause', function() {
    playbtn.style.display = "block";
});
vimeoPlayer.on('play', function() {
    playbtn.style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: you're using https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/ right?

Comment: this would help ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053115/possible-to-trigger-on-vimeo-video-click

Comment: @DerekPollard Yes, using that repo. I checked the API reference and don't see anything related to controls

Comment: @Muath thanks, but the overlay is setup and working properly, only called on play/pause, and when visible and clicked. I just need the display to remain hidden on pause when a share action (or similar) is clicked which is why I'm hoping there's a way to detect those actions.

Answer (score 1):

@froggomad It is not currently possible to listen for action events in the Vimeo player (such as the share, like, embed, and watch later button). As a work around, you can disable those buttons for your videos instead. I believe the only functions that temporarily pause video are share and embed.